# Django Allauth Customized Login Template Not Working

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-allauth

I have customized the login template of allauth with bootstrap styles and widget_tweaks. When I try logging in with that template, It doesn't redirect me to the home page but remains in the same login.html template. However, when I log in with the original template from allauth in `/account/login.html/` everything works well and it redirects me to my homepage. There is something that I'm not customizing right in my custom login.html template.

Below is django-allauth login.html and my custom login.html

**django-allauth login.html**

```html
{% extends "account/base.html" %}

{% load i18n %}
{% load account socialaccount %}

{% block head_title %}{% trans "Sign In" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h1>{% trans "Sign In" %}</h1>

{% get_providers as socialaccount_providers %}

{% if socialaccount_providers %}
<p>{% blocktrans with site.name as site_name %}Please sign in with one
of your existing third party accounts. Or, <a href="{{ signup_url }}">sign up</a>
for a {{ site_name }} account and sign in below:{% endblocktrans %}</p>

<div class="socialaccount_ballot">

  <ul class="socialaccount_providers">
    {% include "socialaccount/snippets/provider_list.html" with process="login" %}
  </ul>

  <div class="login-or">{% trans 'or' %}</div>

</div>

{% include "socialaccount/snippets/login_extra.html" %}

{% else %}
<p>{% blocktrans %}If you have not created an account yet, then please
<a href="{{ signup_url }}">sign up</a> first.{% endblocktrans %}</p>
{% endif %}

<form class="login" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
  {% endif %}
  <a class="button secondaryAction" href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}">{% trans "Forgot Password?" %}</a>
  <button class="primaryAction" type="submit">{% trans "Sign In" %}</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

**my custom login.html**

```html
{% comment %} 
{% extends "layouts/base-fullscreen.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %} Login {% endblock %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block content %}   

    <div class="auth-wrapper">
        <div class="auth-content">
            <div class="auth-bg">
                <span class="r"></span>
                <span class="r s"></span>
                <span class="r s"></span>
                <span class="r"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <div class="mb-4">
                        <i class="feather icon-unlock auth-icon"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="mb-4">Login</h3>

                    <span class="mb-0 text-muted">
                        {% if msg %}
                            {{ msg | safe }}
                        {% else %}
                            Add your credentials
                        {% endif %} 
                    </span>

                    <br />
                    <br />

                    <form method="post" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">

                        {% csrf_token %}                   

                        <div class="md-form mb-2">
                            {% render_field form.login class="form-control" placeholder=form.login.label %}
                        </div>  
                        <span class="text-error">{{ form.login.errors }}</span>

                        <div class="md-form mb-2">
                            {% render_field form.password class="form-control" placeholder=form.password.label %}
                        </div>  
                        <span class="text-error">{{ form.password.errors }}</span>

                        <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><a class="button secondaryAction" href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}">Forgot password?</a>
                        </p>

                        <div class="form-group text-left">
                            <div class="checkbox checkbox-fill d-inline">
                                <!-- <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-fill-1" id="checkbox-fill-a1" checked=""> -->
                                {% render_field form.remember class="form-control" placeholder=form.remember.label type="checkbox"%}
                                <label for="id_remember" class="cr"> Remember me</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {% if redirect_field_value %}
                        <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
                        {% endif %}
                        <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary shadow-2 mb-4">Login</button>

                    </form>

                    <p class="mb-0 text-muted">Don’t have an account? <a href="{% url 'account_signup' %}" >Signup</a></p>
                    <br />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

**allauth settings in settings.py**

```py
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend' 
SITE_ID = 1

ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'   #couterpart to Django's LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT = '/'
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'optional'
```

The other change I've made is to customize the allauth signup form to take extra two fields (first_name and last_name). That one works fine and redirects to the login url

Answer (score 0):

you might be getting an error from the form validator. keep the original form on the page to check if its giving any errors. copy the `{{ form.as_p }}` from the original page 'accounts/login.html' and paste it in your custom template. if there are any errors, it'll display it.

Comment: {{ form.as_p }} works just find. However I cannot add custom classes since I can't access the individual fields

Comment: you can create your own form without having to add {{ form.as_p }}. create your own html form and add the classes you want. design it the way you want, but make sure the names of each field match the names generated by {{ form.as_p }}. this may seem long but that is my usual workaround

Comment: you seem not to get my point. I meant, add `{{ form.as_p }}` at the bottom of your page. if there is any error raised by the form, it'll be displayed. this will help in debugging the issue. Another approach is to add `{{ request.user.is_authenticated }}` to the login page to see if the user has actually been logged in. if not, the form isn't working. if it is, then your redirect is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

this right here is your problem

{% extends "account/base.html" %}

If you have all the boostrap, jquery and widget_tweaks in your local base.html, then thats what you need to extend. The default accounts/base.html provided by django-allauth, does not come customized with bootstrap.

Use:
{% extends "base.html" %} instead